# Django-South - migrating the production server

Tags: django-south

I do all my development on a development server and, when I'm happy with the changes, push the changes up to a production server. Sometimes I'm altering the database and, to accomplish this, I use Django-South.

If I'm altering the models in only one app, I run `python manage.py schemamigration my_app` and then `python manage.py migrate my_app` to update the DB schema for the dev server.

My question is, what's the easiest way to update the Production server once I've pushed my updates to the production server? Since all the migration files in `my_app/migrations/` are also pushed up to the produciton server, do I just run a single `python manage.py migrate my_app` to mimic the DB alterations?

What about if I have made several DB modifications with multiple django-south `migrate my_app` executions - is it still just a single `python manage.py migrate my_app`?

I just want to be careful with my commands so as to not accidentally blow away a chunk of the production database :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the South docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#migrate):

If you want to migrate all the apps at once, run:

```
./manage.py migrate
```

This has the same effect as calling the first example for every app, and will deal with dependencies properly.